# Efeito CSS antes da requisição ao servidor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu queria colocar uma animação CSS enquanto ocorre a requisição do site no servidor. Então encontrei esse código com *Angular*.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
// Criando um interceptador de chamadas http.
// O '$q' é um serviço que permite monitoração de chamadas assincronas  através de 'promisses' que provem callbacks de funcoes.
// $rootScope é o escopo de maior hierarquia em toda aplicação, e pode ser acessado de qualquer nivel
var myHttpInterceptor = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$window', '$templateCache',  'srvMsgBus', function ($q, $rootScope, $window, $templateCache, srvMsgBus) {
return {
// O 'request' ocorre sempre que uma chamada http for iniciada
        'request': function (request) {

            // $emit envia um evento para todos os controlers 'filhos' do controle que o está executando.
            // Este evento pode ser interceptado por outros controllers e serve como meio de comunicação entre eles.
            // Como o $rootScope é o 'pai' de todo e qualquer outro controller, quando ele emite um $emit todos podem interceptar este sinal.
            $rootScope.emit('loading-started');
```

Na `head`

```
<script src="staff/app.js"></script>
```

Na `body`:

```
<div dir-carregando></div>
```

Mas quando vou ver o resultado aparece esse erro no console:

> Falha no carregamento do  com a fonte 
>    “https://ourladyagd.com/components.js”.
>
> ReferenceError: app is not defined[Learn More] app.js:1:1
>
> TypeError: i is undefined[Learn More] bootstrap.min.js:6:2745

Comment: Esse código só dispara um evento, não faz nada relacionado a exibir algo visual.
Se você só quer exibir um please wait, a forma mais imples é colocar ele no seu template html e esconder enquanto o loading não estiver acontecendo, por exemplo com um *ngIf="loading"

Comment: Se quiser mesmo usar esse código do exemplo você precisa colocar o código do componente dir-carregando aqui

Comment: O dir-carregando pelo que entendi quando pesquisei coloquei na primeira linha da body

Comment: Mesmo ele tendo uma requisição ao arquivo app.js na head tenho que coloca na própria estrutura html?

Comment: @SérgioS.Filho Vc tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso sem ser por angula?

Comment: só dá pra dizer se vc mostrar o código

Comment: se vc está usando angular, o ideal é não misturar a forma de fazer com jquery nem a forma de fazer com javascript puro e sim seguir o padrão do angular

Comment: Sei mais de jquery do que angula mas na net não encontrei com jquery por isso fiz este teste.

Comment: Com jquery, antes de vc fazer sua requisição ajax, vc ajusta a visibilidade do please wait para ele aparecer na tela. Depois, quando o callback do ajax retornar, vc ajusta a visibilidade ou display pra esconder o please wait

Comment: @SérgioS.Filho Cara ainda sou novo em js. Vc pode mostra como? Com o que sei não consigo imagina o que vc falou.

Comment: Para você utilizar esse recurso, sua solução deve conter uma aplicação angular. Por favor veja como funciona o framework, sem isso não há como fazê-lo funcionar na sua solução. https://angularjs.org/

Comment: @MoisesMoraes, editei pra deixar o exemplo funcional. Esse script faz uma requisição ajax para um servidor qualquer que eu achei no google e exibe um please wait enquanto a resposta não chega...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exemplo simples com jquery

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <img id="pleaseWait" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-MCCUr1CekTE/VPz4EEqAA1I/AAAAAAAANeA/anbL5xVJ2q4/s1600/11-03%2B~%2BGIF%2B~%2BPlease%2BWait.gif">
    <div id="divResultado" style="padding:50px;"></div>
  </div>

  <script>

    $.get('https://zueii.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path', suaFuncaoDeCallback);

    function suaFuncaoDeCallback(resultado) {

      console.log('resultado retornado do servidor: ', resultado);
      $('#divResultado').html('<div style="font-weight:bold;">Resultado retornado do servidor:</div>' + resultado);
$('#pleaseWait').hide();
    }


  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Documentação jquery ajax**
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Comment: funfou muito obg. Mas queria saber se posso tarda a requisição para que o gif passe mais tempo?

Comment: @MoisesMoraes, pode sim. Você usa o método setTimeout pra rodar algum código só depois de algum tempo. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp